# I need help VGA Dual screens

Tags: windows-10, display, desktop, gaming, desktop-customization

i am using a DVI to VGA converter and a VGA Splitter.
My main display is HDMI, and I have two other monitors, that are VGA. And it won't expand the screen, it will only duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

That is all those adapters are made for, to duplicate. They are not made to expand the screen. To expand the screen you need a video card with support to do so or some sort of other device such as a usb adapter. Those splicer cables are not **smart** in any way. They are simply taking the output of your computer and splicing it into two lines. Since there is no smart interface, this is all they are capable of doing.

Here is an example of a usb to VGA adapter:

[image]

The difference here is that your computer (and the software / drivers with this device) are the smart interface that allows you to extend the monitor, unlike your VGA splitter.  Hopefully that makes sense to you.

Comment: Please mark this as your answer by clicking on the check box so it may help future people who have the same problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A VGA splitter is not able to show different images on different screens.

There might technically be a device that acts as a super wide screen, splitting the image in two pieces, to be displayed on two VGA screens but this will require some serious computing effort (an expensive FPGA) to achieve.